# How do I put a box around a column in a matrix in Latex?

Tags: matrices, boxes, tikz-matrix, nicematrix

I want to build a matrix in Latex code and wrap some components of it with a square. For terms that are on the same line I managed to do it well. But for terms of different lines I am not able to do it. That is, I want to know how to put a rectangle in a column of a matrix.

The matrix I want to reproduce is

[image: reference]

And I tried to build it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,bm}                
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
h_{\mu \nu} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \boxed{h_{00}} & \boxed{h_{01}} & \boxed{h_{02} \quad h_{03}} \\
    \boxed{h_{10}} & \boxed{h_{11}} & \boxed{h_{12} \quad h_{13}} \\
    h_{20} & h_{21} & h_{22} & h_{23} \\
    h_{30} & h_{31} & h_{32} & h_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

but I couldn't fit the rest of the squares. My result is like this:

[image: [my matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G17Yw.png)]

How can I reproduce the reference matrix?

Comment: If you ask the same question on multiple different sites, you should include links to all other versions of your question in every one of your questions!

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/76139623/2777074

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick solution using [TikZ/PGF](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        h =
            \begin{pmatrix}
                \tikz{\node[draw] {S}} & \tikz{\node[draw] {S}} & \tikz{\node[draw, minimum width=1.5cm] {V}} \\
                \tikz{\node[draw] {S}} & \tikz{\node[draw] {S}} & \tikz{\node[draw, minimum width=1.5cm] {V}} \\
                \tikz{\node[draw, minimum height=1.5cm] {V}} & \tikz{\node[draw, minimum height=1.5cm] {V}} & \tikz{\node[draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm] {T}} \\
            \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Result]